# Python: Rearrange an interger number to a largest palindrome number

Tags: python

I have written the following code to solve the topic "Rearrange an interger number to a largest palindrome number"

Example:

**Input data is 485, the output should be 'Not palindrome number'**

**Input data is 445, the output should be 454**

**Input data is 24266, the output should be 62426 (largest palindrome, not 26462)**

Please take a look and help me correct this

The problem I met:
Input 112 -> it just returns 2

Thank you!

```
def largest_palindrome(self, number):
        a = list(str(number))
        duplicate = [item for item, count in collections.Counter(a).items() if count > 1]
        if (round(len(a)/2,0) != len(duplicate)):
            print 'Not palindrome number'
        else:
            uniq = []
            max_item = a[0]
            for i in range (1, len (a)):
                if a[i] > max_item:
                    max_item = a[i]
                    uniq=uniq.append(max_item)
            return uniq
```

Comment: You should mention in your question what is your specific problem so far

Comment: largest palindrome of `123` is `32123` for your case or invalid input?

Comment: To @Vaulstein: it is incorrect. Function does check in the beginning.

Comment: @jamylak It returns the maximum number, not whole number. The problem I met: Input 112 -> it just returns 2

Comment: @Vaulstein if inputting 123, it returns ''Not palindrome number"

Comment: If input is `100`, what should ouput be?

Comment: First of all, you should never do `uniq=uniq.append()`. `append` is a destructive operation (it modifies the list in place instead of of returning a new list). The correct way to do this from `uniq.append(max_item)`

Comment: BTW. Your test for 'palindrome-ability' fails for e.g. `12222`.

Answer (score 3):

```
import itertools

print "".join(max(x for x in itertools.permutations("100") if x == tuple(reversed(x))))
```

In other words: find all permutations, select palindromes, find the maximal one, and show it.

Comment: a `try except ValueError:` maybe for values like `123` or `120`

Comment: It is O(n!) complexity.

Comment: All you are right. I don't consider this approach optimal, only interesting.

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import Counter

def largest_palindrome(num):
    # suppose, num is 34347
    c = Counter(str(num))

    # lst is [('4', 2), ('3', 2), ('7', 1)]
    lst = [(k, v) for k, v in c.items()]

    # lst is [('7', 1), ('4', 2), ('3', 2)]
    # we sort, because we want to process the largest digits first
    # to get the largest palindrome
    lst.sort(key=lambda elt: elt[0], reverse=True)

    head = middle = ''
    for k, v in lst:
        if v % 2 == 1:
            # digit, that number is odd, goes to middle, so '7' goes to middle
            if middle:
                # if some digit is already in middle, we can't place
                # another digit there, e. g. for number '1123'
                print('Not palindrome number')
                return
            middle = k

        # if k is '4', v is 2 -> '44'
        # if k is '7', v is 1 -> '7' * (1 // 2) -> '7' * (0) -> ''
        head += k * (v // 2)

    # head is '43', middle is '7'
    return head + middle + head[::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the code below and it works

```
#Ex1 - Return max proportional number
    def return_arrange(self,number):
        line = list(str(number))
        if len(line)<3:
            print "This number could not be a palindrome number."
            return
        lineA = []
        lineB = []
        i=0        
        while i<len(line):
            for j in range(i+1,len(line)):
                if int(line[i]) == int(line[j]):
                    lineA.append(line[i])
                    line.pop(j)
                    line.pop(i)
                    i=-1
                    break
            if (i>-1):
                lineB.append(line[i])
                line.pop(i)
                i=-1
                if (len(lineB) > 1):
                    print "This number could not be a palindrome number."
                    return
            i=i+1
        lineC = sorted(lineA,reverse=True)+lineB+sorted(lineA)
        return str("".join(lineC))
```